# implementing Left-pointer info right-pointer for java binary tree

Tags: java, pointers, binary-tree, nodes

I have been assigned a homework assignment about converting a list into a binary tree that I am having trouble wrapping my head around the concept, I have been reading through examples but I can't figure out how to actually use it. I need a left node pointer, information, and right pointer. I have found the code to add but don't understand how to use it.

```
class Node{  

    int data;  
    Node left;  
    Node right; 

    public Node(int data) { 
        this.data = data;    
        left = null;     
        right = null;
    }
}
```

is this all I need to do my program, I don't understand how I'm suppose to assign left and right values to each node. Do I need a name for each node I insert? I have pseudo code for my homework such as

```
y = avail;  //whats avail? this is my first line
treeRoot = y;
info(y) = x[2];   //(im inputing from an array) how do i assign this?
lptr(y)= z;     // (left pointer of y gets z) z maybe a pointer?
```

Comment: I dont know what y is and i dont know what avail is. All i have is what he gives us, which is y=avail. i have the program in basic psuedo. I just cant figure out how to assign a left point of a node

Comment: y is my node pointer im assuming and avail is getting an available node

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any more names. Tree structure suggests that each node contains POINTERS to all it's direct descendants. So any node can be found for example by path, that looks like `root->left->left->right->left->right`. So for each node you will instantiate new instance of class `Node`. Then by some algorithm you should find which list item will become root. Then you will assign appropriate items from the list to `root.left = new Node(list[someIndex])` or `root.right = new Node(list[someIndex])`. So now `root.right` is also instance of `Node`. So it also has left and right. And so on.